# Data in SQL Server CE disappears

Tags: c#, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I have a problem using a local SQL Server CE database with C# and EF.

I have a new created database file with one table and three columns. I add some data by using EF. My program, that adds the data, can read that data.

If I open the table with vs2010 the tables are empty. After that I start my program again and now there are no data too.

Anyone an idea what is going wrong here?

Bye

Comment: How do you use EF? D you call SaveChanges()? Do you use DataContextInitializer?

Comment: I use a sql query to see the data in the table. Yes, i call SaveChanges(). If i start my programm that enters the data i can end and start it as often as i whish, every time i see the data. But after a sql query the table is empty.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Go to properties of Sql CE database and set **Copy To Output** to **"If newer"**

Check ones you run the program and updates added go to `$projectname$\bin\Debug` or `\Release` and check database in there.

**Reason behind this:**

Default properties of Normal a database file has Build Action set to "Content" and Copy To Output option set to "Copy Always". then  every time you build, your database from Visual Studio project is copied to your build or release folder and overwrites your existing database with the data added at runtime.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem... The file was replaced. Big thank you :-D